# Azure - how to find permissions at a subscription level?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Have an EA with a few hundred small subscriptions attached below it.
I'm trying to find a script that will list all the email addresses (user account logins) for the "Owner(s)" of each subscription.

So for instance:

```
**Subscription A owners**  
abcdefg@company.com  
defgh@company.com  
ijklmno@company.com

**Subscription B owners**  
defgh@company.com  
test@company.com

**Subscription C owners**  
abcdefg@company.com
```

Comment: what have you tried? what doesnt work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602818/ should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below, it should work.

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzureRmSubscription 
foreach ($sub in $subscriptions)
{
    Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
    Write-Output ("**Subscription " + $sub.Name + " owners**")
    (Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Owner").SignInName 
}
```

[image]